# How to execute hibernate queries in groovy classes?

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, groovy

I am new to Groovy before I was working on java. I am using .groovy classes in AribaWeb. I need to connect to my DB and save the values in the DB.

I have configured the database details in build.xml as follows,

```
    <property value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"/>
    <property value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/test" name="hibernate.connection.url"/>
    <property value="root" name="hibernate.connection.username"/>
    <property value="axxonet" name="hibernate.connection.password"/>
    <property value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" name="hibernate.dialect"/>
    <property value="update" name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" />
```

Now I have a groovy class I need to save the values in DB, How can we create the session and connect to DB and insert the values in database in .groovy class. I am using ant for configuration.

Comment: The shortest answer is: do it the same way as in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 options basically:

1. use `GORM standalone`, as nicely described [here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-gorm/). You'll be able to run a query like:

> def p = Person.findByFirstName(firstName)

or any other GORM or hibernate query

2. use `groovy.sql.Sql` class (see [docs](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html). it doesn't have hibernate on board, but is really powerful if you need to get the things done as simple and as fast as possible:

> def db = [url:'jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDB', user:'sa', password:'', driver:'org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver']
>   def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)
>
> sql.eachRow( "select * from person" ){ row -> 
>      println "$row.id -> $row.userame , $row.firstName"
>   }

Answer (score 0):

First, import where the `Session` variable is.  Then run the query.  For example:

```
import java.util.List

import org.hibernate.Query
import org.hibernate.Session

Session session = HibernateUtils.getSession()
def query = <YOUR INSERT QUERY STATEMENT>
def queryResults = session.createQuery(query)
def result = queryResults.executeUpdate()
```